# Referring to JavaScript Libraries in tag names?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I'm a bit confused on tagging and references to Javascript libraries. I sometimes use OpenLayers and Leaflet and have seen questions tagged without the '.js' affix (e.g. D3), while in other instances, the '.js' is preserved (e.g. three.js)

Should the .js be dropped if there exists a non-js version of a library/software (such as ArcGIS and arc.js) so as to not confuse people, or does it simply follow the naming conventions adopted by the communities that use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tag naming conventions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) say to:

> - Avoid punctuation (which can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL)

which suggests that reviewing `.js` in any tag names that include it may be desirable.

To see those that might need attention, click https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartodb.js+or+node.js+or+odyssey.js+or+three.js+or+arc.js+or+dc.js+or+d3.js+or+crossfilter.js, or type `.js` into the tag search bar.

There seem to be at least four variations to how `"js"` tags have been formulated:

- [node.js](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.js) - dot before `js`
- [ext-js](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ext-js) - hyphen before `js`
- [proj4js](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj4js) - nothing before `js`
- [leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaflet) - drop `js`

I think we should:

1. drop `js` if that leaves a tag name that is not easily confused with another, or hard to recognize by those that need it; and then to
2. use a hyphen before `js` if additional disambiguation is needed